# ASP.NET MVC 5 routing restriction

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, url-routing

I've updated my code to use Area as suggested but the problem still exist. `/dashboard` is still available.

My Controllers folder has HomeController and AccountController. I have Areas/Admin/Controllers/DashboardController.cs

Problem:

1. My area admin controller can be accessed like this `/admin/dashboard`, but the problem is it can also be accessed using `/dashboard` -> this should show 404

here is my RouteConfig:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                namespaces: new[] { "project.Controllers" }
            );
```

AdminAreaRegistration:

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
        {
            context.MapRoute(
                "Admin_default",
                "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                namespaces: new[] { "project.Areas.Admin.Controllers" }
            );

        }
```

Comment: `project.controllers.admin` namespace is within `project.controllers` namespace try changing the name space for admin to one that is not a child of `project.controllers`. something like `project.admin` and see if that works

Comment: This sounds like a good time to perhaps look at Areas..

Answer (score 4):

The `/dashboard` call is routed by the `Default` routing rule.

You can make the `Default` not to process the calls made to the `dashboard` controller by adding a constraint.

For example:

In the default routing rule you can add a constraint like the following:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    namespaces: new[] { "project.Controllers" },
    constraints: new { controller = new Constraints.IsNotDashboard() }
);
```

Then, you can declare the constraint like this:

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Routing;

public class IsNotDashboard : IRouteConstraint
{
    public IsNotDashboard()
    {
    }

    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        string controller = values["controller"].ToString().ToLower();

        return controller != "dashboard";
    }
}
```

With this constraint, all calls that match the `dashboard` controller will not be processed by the `Default` routing rule.

Comment: the constraints work, but it's very tedious to add additional constraints when i create more admin area controllers as they will also be routed to default right?

Comment: @HeeroYuy you could have a single constraint for all new controllers. Another way is to check the `httpContext.Request.Url.LocalPath` property, and if it starts with `/admin` or not. If that seems a bit hacky to you, consider using Areas where they have this behavior by default.

Comment: @HeeroYuy I noticed you changed your question and you now are using areas. Are you still having the issue? Perhaps you have two `Dashboard` controllers in your project? and one of them is outside the area's namespace

Comment: I've deleted the Dashboard controller outside Area. But i've already found a fix to my problem. I posted below. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys.

After searching the net, I finally found what works best for my problem.

The problem was that all controllers are being handled as well in `Default` route, so I just added controller constraints to `Default`. This way `Default` route will only accept request on specified controllers. Below is my new RouteConfig

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                constraints: new { controller = @"(Account|Manage|Home)" }
            );
```

Comment: You added equal check in `constraints`. Can we add not-equal check in `constraints` like; `constraints: new { controller != @"(Account|Manage|Home)" }` ?